# DocuSign Web Sign can't finish

Tags: json, docusignapi

I have an issue with the DocuSign Web Sign UI. 
 I create an envelope and add tabs via CreateTabs API call using the JSON request below. 
 The tabs contains initial value e.g "Enter date", so the signing person has a guideline what he should type in the fields. 
 Well, when I fill out the document on the DocuSign sign page the "Finish" button appears, but nothing happens when I click on it.

I figure out that it has something to do with the initial value of the created tabs. Without the initial values I can finish the document. 
It works also if I try to create a similar template with the DocuSign editor. 
Why is it not working in my case?

If you want to have a look at the issue, I can send you a pm with the link for signing the specific envelope.

Here is the JSON I use:

```
{
"dateSignedTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSDate2_14>>",
    "documentId": "1",
    "font": "LucidaConsole",
    "fontColor": "Black",
    "name": "DSDate2_14",
    "pageNumber": "1"
}],
"dateTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText9_2>>",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "locked": "false",
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "name": "DSText9_2",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "requireAll": "true",
    "required": "true",
    "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
    "shared": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText9_2",
    "value": "Enter date",
    "width": 100
}],
"fullNameTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSFullname3_15>>",
    "documentId": "1",
    "font": "LucidaConsole",
    "fontColor": "Black",
    "name": "DSFullname3_15",
    "pageNumber": "1"
}],
"noteTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSNote8_12>>",
    "documentId": "1",
    "height": 39,
    "name": "DSNote8_12",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "tabLabel": "\\\\*DSNote8_12",
    "value": "Type note-text here",
    "width": 100
}],
"numberTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText10_3>>",
    "concealValueOnDocument": "true",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "locked": "false",
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "name": "DSText10_3",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "required": "true",
    "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
    "shared": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText10_3",
    "value": "Tax Number",
    "width": 100
}],
"radioGroupTabs": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "groupName": "Income",
    "radios": [{
        "anchorString": "<<DSRB5_9>>",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "required": "true",
        "value": ">10k"
    },
    {
        "anchorString": "<<DSRB6_10>>",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "required": "true",
        "value": "<15k"
    },
    {
        "anchorString": "<<DSRB7_11>>",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "required": "true",
        "value": "<25k"
    }],
    "requireAll": "true",
    "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
    "shared": "true"
}],
"signHereTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSSignature1_13>>",
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "DSSignature1_13",
    "pageNumber": "1"
}],
"ssnTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText13_6>>",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "locked": "false",
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "name": "DSText13_6",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "requireAll": "true",
    "required": "true",
    "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
    "shared": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText13_6",
    "value": "Enter SSN",
    "width": 141
}],
"textTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText4_1>>",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "height": 20,
    "locked": "false",
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "name": "DSText4_1",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "requireAll": "true",
    "required": "true",
    "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
    "shared": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText4_1",
    "validationMessage": "Enter only letters",
    "validationPattern": "^[a-zA-Z ]{1,}$",
    "value": "Enter pan",
    "width": 241
},
{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText14_7>>",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "height": 18,
    "locked": "false",
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "name": "DSText14_7",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "requireAll": "true",
    "required": "true",
    "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
    "shared": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText14_7",
    "value": "None",
    "width": 162
},
{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText15_8>>",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "height": 20,
    "locked": "false",
    "name": "DSText15_8",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "required": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText15_8",
    "value": "Enter Code",
    "width": 168
}],
"zipTabs": [{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText11_4>>",
    "concealValueOnDocument": "true",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "locked": "false",
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "name": "DSText11_4",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "required": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText11_4",
    "value": "Zip Number",
    "width": 100
},
{
    "anchorString": "<<DSText12_5>>",
    "concealValueOnDocument": "true",
    "disableAutoSize": "true",
    "documentId": "1",
    "locked": "false",
    "maxLength": 4000,
    "name": "DSText12_5",
    "pageNumber": "1",
    "requireAll": "true",
    "required": "true",
    "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "true",
    "shared": "true",
    "tabLabel": "\\*DSText12_5",
    "useDash4": "true",
    "value": "Zip4-5 ",
    "width": 100
}]
```

}

**Update**

DocuSign fixed this issue in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the **Finish** button will be enabled (i.e., clickable) until all required fields are populated with *valid* values. For example, the JSON that you included in your post above contains a **dateTab** with a default value of "Enter date". If the user does not replace this default value with a valid date, then the **Finish** button won't be enabled (clickable).

The same behavior holds true for any other required fields within the document that require a specific type (or format) of data -- the **Finish** button won't be enabled until all required fields are populated with *valid* values.

Comment: The fields are populated with valid values and the button is clickable, but nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: Perhaps try testing the same scenario using another type of browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc.) -- this shouldn't be a browser issue, but you never know.

Comment: If you can't get it to work in another type of browser, I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign support, since this issue is related to the signer experience in the Web UI. Support should be able to help you figure out what it is about the state of the fields in the envelope that's preventing the Finish button from working.  (Note: Support may try to direct you to StackOverflow to get help on your own, if they realize you created the Envelope with the API -- but they are the right ones to help with this issue, not StackOverflow. This is an issue with the signer experience, not an API issue.)

Comment: I followed your advise and opened a support case at DocuSign